# Using Pseudo inside stack parameter in cloud-formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use a Pseudo variable inside parameter definition  in the cloud-formation stack I am creating:

The parameter is defined like that:

```
 S3LogBucketPrefix:
    Description: Supplier logs S3 Delivery group folder structure

Type: String
    Default: source=aws/account=${AWS::AccountId}/region=${AWS::Region}/env=nonprod/
```

and when I use it in my resource I tried both:

```
  Bucket:
    Condition: Launch2Engine
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      LoggingConfiguration:
        DestinationBucketName: !Ref S3LogBucketName
        LogFilePrefix: !Join
              - ''
              - - !Ref S3LogBucketPrefix
                - !Ref BucketName
```

And:

```
  Bucket:
    Condition: Launch2Engine
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      LoggingConfiguration:
        DestinationBucketName: !Ref S3LogBucketName
        LogFilePrefix: !Join
              - ''
              - - !Sub ${S3LogBucketPrefix}
                - !Ref BucketName
```

But The Pseudo doesn't seem to be replaced with the value as seen in the picture below:

[image]

Is that even possible to use Pseudo inside a parameter? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Sadly, it is not possible to use pseudo-parameters inside a `parameter`.

Comment: You'll need to use something like fn::sub or fn::join